# Does this javascript regex replace whitespace?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm browsing through the code for twitter bootstrap and I've coma across this snippet a few times.

```
href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') //strip for ie7
```

Regexes are my blindspot and I can't figure out most of them. What is it replacing? Is it whitespace after the #?

Side note. Can anyone recommend a good source for regex tuition?

Comment: Side Answer: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what it's looking for:

```
.*     # any number of characters (optional)
(?=    # open a lookahead
#      # find a hash tag
[^\s]+ # at least one non-whitespace character
$      # end of line
)      # close the lookahead
```

So, for example, it matches what comes before a hash tag:

```
replace this!#foobar   <-- matches: replace this!
hello world#goodbye    <-- matches: hello world
no match here !        <-- doesn't match anything because there is no hash
what?#                 <-- does not match because there is nothing after the hash
what?# asd             <-- does not match because there is a whitespace-character
```

Comment: a few examples of valid and invalid matches would go nicely with that answer ;)

Comment: @alan: Absolutely brilliant! This is the kind of clear answer I was hoping for.

Comment: @JamesSouth to be exact: it matches `#foobar` and `#goodbye`, not `replace this!` and `hello world`. It doesn't match `#f oobar` or `#` though.

Comment: @Christoph: No. The hash and everything after it is enclosed in a positive lookahead, which does not participate in the match. The only thing that matches the regex is what is before the lookahead.

Comment: sry, i confused the word match. what i really ment: the replace returns you the `#foobar` and `#goodbye` because it matches the rest of the string and replaces it with `''`. Some kind of double negation... My fault;)

Comment: @Christoph: Yeah I figured as much. Did some tests to be sure.